# Ajaxbased Combobox attributes access in ASP.Net

Tags: .net, asp.net, combobox, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Hi
I am using ajax based autocomplete combobox in asp.net by official Microsoft Ajaxtoolkit,  I am fetching three attributes behind it, one is its text, second is its value, third is another attribute related to each value, coming from database, i can access value and text, but cant access the third attribute from it, is there any option to do so, like we do SelectedItem.Value to get value, SelectedItem.Text for text, for any other attribute, what we can do?

Many Thanks
Atif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that by appending  the third attribute with the value part

what i mean is when you are fetching the value from database con cat both the values with a separator and split it.

for sql server concatenating use this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: I have seen in Java Flex, you can fetch thousands of attributes in combobox and access it with attribute property, is this not possible in .Net?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the attributes value of Dropdown from codebehind using "key" "Value" combination, please check below syntax:

To set:

```
ddl.Attributes.Add("key", "value");
```

To Fetch:

```
string val = ddl.Attributes["key"].ToString();
```

You have to use this key and value according to your logic and condition.